# Query based on the combination of two columns in Rails Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a user model that has two columns i.e name and label. 
Combination of these columns is given in an array-like below

`name_and_label_array = [["name1", "label1"], ["name2", "label2"], ["name3", label3"]`

I want to query such that only those users should return whose **name and label combination** is present in the GIVEN array(name_and_label_array).

I tried with below code but it throws MYSQL syntax error

`User.where("[name, label] in ?", name_and_label_array)`

Please suggest some efficient ways to handle this in ActiveRecord.

In raw MYSQL, we can write in below way

`select name, label  from users where (name, label) in (('name1', 'label1'), ('name2', 'label2'));`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if change `[name, label] in ?` to `(name, label) in ?`

Comment: @Vasilisa got same error ```TypeError: can't quote Array```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the placeholders for the array of arrays.

```
placeholders = (['(?)'] * name_and_label_array.size).join(',')
User.where("(name, label) in (#{placeholders})", *name_and_label_array)
```